# How to remove X-AspNetMvc-Version from header response without touching source code file (Global.asax.cs)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to disable the `X-AspNetMvc-Version` from the response header of a large number of applications. The server where the applications are hosted has just the content and config files `Global.asax, web.config, app.config` for the application and source code files (*.cs) reside with some other team.

I could only find the solution as adding 
`MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;`
to `Global.asax.cs`. 
Any alternative solution(s) that involves working with any config file(s)?

Answer (score 7):

Set enableVersionHeader to false in your web.config is an alternate, I would prefer the web.config change to a handler solution like you have, obviously, since you will not need to access global.asax.cs to make the change:

just copy this line into the web.config’s `<system.web>` section:

```
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableversionheader(v=vs.110).aspx

http://madskristensen.net/post/Remove-the-X-AspNet-Version-header

Comment: Thanks Brian, however the solution you talked of takes care of X-AspNet-Version while I need it for X-AspNetMvc-Version.

Comment: I see, sorry, it looks like you have the best and only solution for ASP.NET MVC: http://arturito.net/2011/10/21/how-to-remove-server-x-aspnet-version-x-aspnetmvc-version-and-x-powered-by-from-the-response-header-in-iis7/

Comment: That's not the right answer as stated by Chitra Belwal

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the only way is to use the following code in your Global.asax:
MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but no marked answer. I was able to achieve this using the code below. In your global.asax.cs we can remove any header.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
   if (HttpContext.Current != null)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("x-aspnet-version");                
   }
}
```